# How to select only lessons which belong to a particular course in a create form using Laravel and Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Course and Lesson models and I want to first select a Course and then only the lessons which belong to that course to be available for selection on a dropdown list.
I have created the pivot tabla course_lesson and the relashionship works  ok.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <select name="course_id" class="browser-default custom-select">
            <option selected>Choose course</option>
            @foreach($courses as $course)
            <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->title}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="lesson_id" class="browser-default custom-select">
            <option selected>Choose lesson</option>
            @foreach($courses as $course)
            @foreach($course->lesson as $lesson)

                <option value="{{$lesson->id}}">{{$lesson->title}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Better load the lessons firing ajax on course select.

Comment: I am working on this. But can it be done in blade, without Ajax and Jquery?

Comment: No you can't. You have to use javascript if you want to filter lesson with the change on courses. You can follow this post on how to load items with ajax https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011235/6792374.